# Clarification about storing courses in database

Tags: database

suppose if i need to take different college details and store courses offered by them into databases.Assume number of courses are different for different colleges.how table should be designed to store courses.

here these courses should be able retrieved for further processing

can any one suggest idea for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with 2 tables, 1 for `Institution` (the university/college), and 1 for `Course`.  The `Course` table should have a foreign key `institution_id` to the `Institution` table.

This way you can have as many courses as you want for any college, and looking up courses for a college is as simple as doing a query on `institution_id`.

Naturally, this is only a start, you will probably have to expand on this.  For example, you might want to have another table like `College` that has a a foreign key to `Institution`, to model the fact that sometimes universities have many sub-schools within them.  You could also have `Institution` rows reference other `Institution` rows to model the same thing; what you want to do depends on the details.